# how to dynamically create oj-input-text or any other oj- element in page Oracle Jet?

Tags: oracle-jet

I am trying to add form element dynamically/Programatically in form. Actually I am working on small form builder sample with Java. So trying to create element on button click.

Comment: This is something you can google. Do some code and post specific question related to an issue you are facing. SO is to help you when you have some code already. To get started Google is the friend.

Comment: Thanks for you advice. Oracle Jet framework is new and google doesn't have answer for my question that's why I posted to find some help. My question very simple I want to create Oracle Jet component dynamically which can we be recognised by View.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with JET v4.0.0, the UI elements are HTML5 custom elements.  So you should be able to create the element just as you would any other element.  The attributes that are defined in the JSDocs are HTML attributes and would again, follow the same methods.  I'm not a Java programmer so I can't show you a code sample, but a google search on how to create HTML elements in Java, should get you going in the proper direction.